# forkJoined observables not rendering output in the component

Tags: angular, angularfire2

All of my posts data is located at `/posts`

When uploading new posts - postId's are also saved in `/people/${userId}/posts`

Have a `getFeed(uri, fetchPostDetails = false)`

When getting All Posts feed (general feed page) it uses uri `posts` & false for the fetchPostDetails and retrieves bc all of the post data is there.

**Problem**
When retrieving user posts and post data it will go to get user's postsId's and then get that post data individually. So it creates multiple observables's and returns a forkJoined Observable to render in the Component. Can't get it to render.

```
// located angularFireHelper  service 

getUserFeed(uri, fetchPostDetails = true) {
    let query = null;
    query = this.database.list(`/${uri}`,
        {
            query: {
                orderByKey: true,
            }
        });


    // IF not general feed fetchPostDetails
    if (fetchPostDetails) {
        return query.map((posts) => {
            console.log('User page so fetchPostDetails called');

            let source = [];
            source = posts.map(post => {
                // returns an Observable
                return this.database.object(`/posts/${post.$key}`);
            });

            return Observable.forkJoin(source);
        });
}


// userFeed.component.ts
ngOnInit() {
    this.componentName = 'user page component';
    this.user = this.afAuth.authState;
    this.getUsersFeedPosts();
}


getUsersFeedPosts() {
    this.user.subscribe(
        (value) => {
            console.log('value', value.uid);
            this.currentUser = value;
            this.afHelperService.getUserFeed(`people/${this.currentUser.uid/posts`).subscribe(
                (posts) => {
                        console.log('posts', posts);
                        this.userPosts = posts;
                    });
}


// userFeed.component.html
{{ userPosts | json }}


// In the console for posts (userPosts) it shows 

posts ForkJoinObservable {_isScalar: false, sources: Array(4), resultSelector: null}
enter code here
sources: (4) [FirebaseObjectObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable]
```

**UPDATE**
Changing the angularFireHelperService code to the following worked. Not 100% sure why this is the only way I could get it to work. Seems like an antipattern using zip operator.

```
if (fetchPostDetails) {
    return query.switchMap((posts) => {
        console.log('User page so fetchPostDetails called');

        let source = [];
        source = posts.map(post => {
            // returns an Observable
            return this.database.object(`/posts/${post.$key}`);
        });

            return Observable.zip(...source);
    });
```

Comment: I guess `query.map(` should be `query.switchMap(`

Comment: Or `.flatMap` - when you’re returning an observable, you probably want that to resolved as part of the chain, not passed on as the value.

Comment: the map part seems to working the way I want it. It is providing the postId's (post.$key)'s that I need. I am ultimately returning the Observable.forkJoin(source). I tried both switchMap and flatMap they caused a it not to return (log) anything in the component.ts

Comment: got it to work with the following code not entirely sure how at this point this works. Zip operator from what I understand will slow things down as it waits for the observables to finish before returning

Comment: switch map ended up helping me to figure it out but still feels like I am using and antipattern using zip operator as that was the other way I was able to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You sould extend your stream using switchMap. Change to **[`query.switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html)**

```
if (fetchPostDetails) {
        return query.switchMap((posts) => {
            console.log('User page so fetchPostDetails called');
            let source = [];
            source = posts.map(post => {
                // returns an Observable
                return this.database.object(`/posts/${post.$key}`);
            });
            return Observable.forkJoin(source);
 });
```

Comment: using switchMap then .zip operator and the dotdotdot argument pattern ended up working - updated the quesiton.